# Array,pointer getting error [warning]Braces around scalar initializer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int *A[3] = {{1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1}};
    int *B[4] = {{2,2,2},{2,22,2},{3,3,3},{3,3,3}};
    int *C[3];
    multiply(A, 1, 2, B, 3, 4, C);
    printf("A matrix:\n");
    printMatrix(A,3,4);
    printf("B matrix:\n");
    printMatrix(B,4,3);
    printf("C matrix:\n");
    printMatrix(C,3,3);
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Its just int main part!

I'm getting the error

> [warning]Braces around scalar initializer

in line:

```
int *A[3] = {{1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1}};
```

Why? Is it because of my mistake or compiler version difference?

Comment: `A` is array of `int*`.

Answer (score 4):

`A` is an array of `int *`, not a 2D array.  Therefore, the initializers should be scalar values which are an `int *`.

If you have C99 or C11, you can rescue the code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void printMatrix(int *x[], int y, int z);
extern void multiply(int *A[], int n1, int n2, int *B[], int n3, int n4, int *C[3]);

int main(void)
{
    int *A[3] = {(int []){1,1,1,1}, (int []){1,1,1,1}, (int []){1,1,1,1}};
    int *B[4] = {(int []){2,2,2}, (int []){2,22,2}, (int []){3,3,3}, (int []){3,3,3}};
    int *C[3];
    multiply(A, 1, 2, B, 3, 4, C);
    printf("A matrix:\n");
    printMatrix(A, 3, 4);
    printf("B matrix:\n");
    printMatrix(B, 4, 3);
    printf("C matrix:\n");
    printMatrix(C, 3, 3);
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This uses C99 compound literals in the initializers.

However, you will need to be careful to allocate the right amount of space inside `multiply()` to store the data for each row in `C`.  You'll also have to know how to release the allocated space.